# Return 0 if no records found on COUNT(*) query In MYSQL

Tags: mysql

I want to get '0' when no records found on execution of `sql` query. I try so many things like **ifnull(count(*),0)** but not gives me the result which i want.

Query is mention as below :

```
SELECT chat_room_id,COUNT(*) FROM chat  WHERE sender_id=13 GROUP BY chat_room_id
```

It gives me the result as below:

```
__________________________
| chat_room_id | Count(*) |
--------------------------
```

It not return any 'null' or '0' , so i want to get '0' OR 'null' if no records found.

Comment: shouldn't your query  be SELECT chat_room_id,COUNT(*) FROM chat  WHERE sender_id=13 GROUP BY chat_room_id

Comment: even if sender 13 does not exist you want a record returned?

Comment: Sorry, I edited my question, It is chat_room_id rather than sender_id.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as there is a table `Chats` with field `sender_id` then the following will return a row even if the sender_Id 13 does not exist in the table.

```
set @sender = 13;
set @chats  = (select count(*) from Chat where sender_id = @sender);

select @sender AS sender_id, IFNULL(@chats,0) AS Count_chats
;
```

<kbd>[See this working at SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/caf24/3)</kbd>

Comment: a pleasure, guess you will adjust it for chat_room_id, cheers

Answer (score 0):

**AFTER YOUR EDIT CHANGES**

Try this:

```
SELECT distinct c1.chat_room_id, 
(select count(*) from chat c2 c2.chat_room_id = c1.chat_room_id and c2.sender_id = 13)
FROM chat c1
```

**Pay attention:**

A table named CHAT I suppose contains all chats in your DB and no the messages and senders.

Instead if you have a table named CHAT_ROOM with the list of all chats so your query becomes:

```
SELECT chat_room_id, 
(SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM chat 
WHERE chat.chat_room_id = chat_room.chat_room_id AND chat.sender_id = 13)
FROM chat_room
```

Comment: You do not mention what is c2 in your first query. In second query it return 0 for all chatrooms.

Comment: Fixed, was a fault. But you don't tell me your correct table structure.

Comment: I have two tables in my db chat and chat_room. In chat[id,message,sender_id,chat_room_id] ,  In chat_room[id,created_at] . so i want count of chats for all chatrooms.

Answer (score 0):

You can not query data which is not in the source tables or which is not available with calculation.

If you have a table which contains all available chat rooms, you can use that table to get the desired record with a simple query using `LEFT OUTER JOIN`

```
SELECT
  CR.chat_room_id,
  COUNT(C.chat_room_id)
FROM
  chat_rooms CR
  LEFT JOIN chat C
    ON CR.chat_room_id = C.chat_room_id
      AND C.sender_id = 13  -- Moved from WHERE to keep all non-matching records from CR
GROUP BY
  CR.chat_room_id
```

If you do not have a specific table, you can use `LEFT OUTER JOIN` and a `subquery` to get the result:

```
SELECT
  CR.chat_room_id,
  COUNT(C.chat_room_id)
FROM
  (SELECT DISTINCT chat_room_id FROM chat) CR
  LEFT JOIN chat C
    ON CR.chat_room_id = C.chat_room_id
      AND C.sender_id = 13 -- Moved from WHERE to keep all non-matching records from CR
GROUP BY
  CR.chat_room_id
```

[**SQLFiddle demo** for the second query](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d2b7b/1)

Comment: COUNT(*) will never be NULL, it will be at least 1. If you want 0 you need to count on a column from the left joined table (i.e COUNT(c.chat_room_id))

Comment: @Pred , It always return 1 for all chat_room_id.

Comment: @ckpatel Which one returns always 1? Are there multiple chat_rooms in your db? What do you see if select only the distinct char_room_id list?

Comment: @Pred Still, it makes no sense to use COALESCE (see my previous comment)

Comment: @Pred, Yes there are multiple chat_rooms in my DB , Can you specify how can i execute distinct chat_room_id list .

Comment: @ckpatel `SELECT DISTINCT chat_room_id FROM chat` if there is no `chat_room` table OR `SELECT DISTINCT chat_room_id FROM chat_room` if the `chat_room` exists

Comment: @Pred , It gives me the list of chat_rooms .

Comment: @ckpatel Did you run the above query without any modification? (Which one?)

Comment: @Pred ,Above query means your commented query Or answered query?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62172/discussion-between-ckpatel-and-pred).

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking to return all the chat_room_ids in case the sender id does not exist?

like, if say sender_id 9 does not exist, what are you looking to return?

In case you wanted something like

chat_room_id  count
NO_RECORDS    0

then the below query will work:

```html
declare @Chat_Room_Id varchar(3),
@Count int

select @Chat_Room_Id = cast(chat_room_id as varchar(3)), @Count = count(*)  from chat where sender_id=13 group by chat_room_id

select coalesce(@Chat_Room_Id, 'NO RECORDS') chat_room_id, coalesce(@Count, 0) count
```

In case I did not understand, can you please clarify further?

-hth
Sourav

Answer (score -2):

you can use  mysql_affected_rows(); method to get the details of rows affected with your query.

check [this](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mysql_affected_rows.asp)
and [this](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-affected-rows.php)

Comment: i dont see `php` on question tags

Comment: @Sharky - This is not for php , i need it for mysql only.

Answer (score -2):

You can put the sql in a sub query this will always return a row

```
select sub.id,sub.counter from (select sender_id as id,count(*) as counter from chat where sender_id = 13) sub
```

This will return 0 if there are no records or 1 if there are.

Comment: does not work with `GROUP BY` as demonstrated by op.

Comment: You can move the Group By to the outer select.